# Any hack to get rid of the "Too many password attempts" lock?

Tags: security, lock-screens, password, 2-step-verification

My kids often play with my phone which has a pattern lock screen, and it gets locked due to many attempts, then the phone is locked out and requires a password.

I use 2-step verification, so in order to unlock the phone, I must get a connected computer, and regenerate a password and reconnect the email and other programs in it.
This all process is redundant to me and very annoying and frustrating.

Is there any possible way to disable this nasty "feature"?

p.s., my phone is rooted of course, if that says anything.

Comment: Nice Question...

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution would be to remove the lock screen but that leads to a whole new set of problems.

I would recommend switching to another type of lock screen such as PIN input or password input. That way the OK button must be pressed in order to submit a password attempt.

The most effective solution of course - don't give your smartphone to your kids. :-)

Comment: I do need the lock screen, I just don't want any features I never asked for.

Comment: Use a third party lockscreen like WidgetLocker. It should work as intended

Comment: @Sparks did u try it?

Comment: Paid user. I use the ICS-like animation where one has to drag the lock icon in one of four directions to either unlock or directly launch an app of choice. You can also set it to unlock using a hardware button like the home or back keys. Mind you - there's zero security this way.

Comment: @Shimmy - I've written about WidgetLocker, NOT GoLocker. :-) | https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker

Comment: oh it's a paid app, i don't use paid apps (and yes im a developer myself), anyway, it doesn't look like it's gonna solve my issues mentioned in my previous comments.

Comment: In order to unlock my S2, all i do is drag the lock icon downward and presto- i'm at my launcher homescreen. Of course, no pin/pattern lock enabled.

Comment: OK forget it. I wish I woulda been an Android developer, I would then make a custom ROM disabling too-many-attempts lockout.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [Secure Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin), although it does not always work as advertised. I use this with Locale to simply disable the lockscreen when I'm in certain locations.

Answer (score 1):

Why not install a [sandbox](http://www.famigo.com/sandbox/) which will prevent this kind of thing from happening?

It is a form of parental control and content management so that certain apps are locked out from kids.

And the bonus - with the sandbox activated, you can still give it to your kids to play with. And no messing about with settings, deleting certain things such as contacts, sms etc.

For example (*take this with a pinch of salt here*), accidentally buying an app from the Google Play Store without your knowledge.